# Increasing Replication Factor in YugabyteDB live cluster?

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Is there a way to go from RF1 -> RF3 -> RF5 cluster using the default yb-master + yb-tserver components (not using `yugabyted` cli) ?

And if that is not possible, how ready is the `yugabyted` join that is in beta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yugabyted` cli doesn't let you change the RF natively. By design, when you start a 1 node cluster it is started as RF1. As you add the second and third node, the RF is automatically bumped to 3 and then it remains 3 when you add more nodes subsequently.

For changing the RF, you can use the `yb-admin` command [modify-placement-info](https://docs.yugabyte.com/latest/admin/yb-admin/#modify-placement-info).